# For Each.. is not itirating through cells in a column

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop

The end goal is to loop through each cell in a column. If the value in each of those cells are "0" and te value of the cell to the right of it is "None", then it removes that entire row. After that it should itirate to the next cell and do the same thing. However, I noticed that it will only do it for one, or just a few cells at a  time.

```
'remove names of people with no permissions and no group access
    For Each c In Range("C:C")
        If c.Value = "0" Then
            If c.Offset(0, 1).Value = "None" Then
                c.EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        End If
    Next c
```

Comment: Don't loop. Use `Range.AutoFilter`, filter, then delete visible cells.

Comment: Certainly don't loop through all million rows and if you do loop, do it backwards.

Comment: it's because you're deleting rows from the top down.  Use a for loop and go from the bottom up (step -1) or better yet, use BigBen's approach as it will be *much* faster.

Comment: @BigBen I actually figured it out. Thank you for your time.